# local rails on Mac OSX loses connection to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

On occasion, my local Rails app loses its connection to MySQL. I get some error that the connection failed, but if I just refresh the page, it works fine. This has never happpened in my STAGE or PROD environments (I deploy to Ubuntu), so it has not been that big a deal.
Does this happen to anybody else?  Is there something I can do to fix it?  Is it MySQL or Ruby?

Comment: Pasting in a copy of error message/stack trace would probably help you get more responses rather than saying you get 'some error' which is a wee bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having this problem a while back (before i upgraded to Leopard?).  They're tricky to diagnose, but have a look at logfiles, and try setting "wait_timeout" longer (you shouldn't have to mess with "max_connections".  See:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/23/how-to-track-down-the-source-of-aborted_connects/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/communication-errors.html

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-database-myisam-innodb-1634.html

I *think* i followed Dan Benjamin's MySql install blog to not have problems:

http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 3):

Look like the best solution to this is to install the platform specific mysql driver.  
`sudo gem install mysql`